# How to count the impact of aging on a variable using R?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, variables, var

Basically, I want to create  a function that changes the value of salary over time, based on the change that happen to the "years of experience" variable, since salary is nothing but 200* years_of_exp*0. 19, and plot the mean of salary over time.

so I have a dataframe presented like this:

| age | sex | edu | statu | exp_y | sal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | f | no | ac | 2 | 76 |
| 20 | m | low | ac | 15 | 570 |
| 4 | m | low | n_ac | 0 | 0 |
| 24 | m | no | ac | 10 | 380 |
| 36 | f | hiegh | ac | 18 | 684 |
| 42 | f | low | ac | 17 | 646 |

And i want to plot the mean of the salary "sal" (sal=200*exp_y*0.19) over time (I chouse 30 years); so I create the aging function :

```
aging <- function(df,t)
{
  age <<- age+1
  exp_y[i,t] <<- exp_y[i,t-1]+1
  statut[i,t] <<- statut[i,t-1]
  sal[i,t] <<- 200*0.19*exp_y[i,t]
  return(mean(sal))
}
```

then I tried to plot the mean over time using this code:

```
hor <- 30
for (t in 1:hor) {
  for (i in df) {
    plot(aging, type='l')
  }
}
```

but i end up with this message error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erreur d'évaluation de l'argument 'x' lors de la sélection d'une méthode pour la fonction 'mean' : 

object 'sal' not found
Error in x(x) : argument "t" is missing, with no default
```

Any ideas pleas,

kind regards

Comment: `aging` is your function's name, so you can't plot a function, yo want to plot what that function returns. In addition, when you create `aging` function, you use some objects like `age`, `sal` or `statut` which are not defined, so, firts you need to define correctly your function.

Comment: Also `sal=200*(exp)*0.19` makes no sense: you have provided no argument to `exp`.

Comment: (exp) are years of experience for each individual so sal=200*(exp)*0.19

Comment: Why not share what you want to achieve in the end? That way we can suggest more appropriate calculation/function.

Comment: Basically, I want to create  a function that changes the value of salary over time, based on the change that happen to the "years of experience" variable, since salary is nothing but 200*years_of_exp*0. 19, and plot the mean of salary over time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your function is so complex, if salary is indeed just `200*years_of_experience*0.19`.

```
sal <- function(exp_y) 200*exp_y*0.19

plotting_df <- data.frame(hor = 1:30,
                          sal = sapply(1:30, sal))

plot(sal~hor, plotting_df, type="l")
```

[image]